# Error when trying to create a private device using graph and power automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I'm trying to automate the creation of private channels in a team using HTTP Request action from Power Automate. I managed to create channels whose privacy is "standard" without a problem, but when I try to create a private one appears the following error:

```
"message": "channel cannot be null.Parameter name: channel"
```

The body of the HTTP call is:

```js
{
  "@@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Teams.Core.channel",
  "membershipType": "private",
  "displayName": "My First Private Channel",
  "description": "This is my first private channel",
  "members": [
    {
      "@@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "user@@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('{user_id}')",
      "roles": ["owner"]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see I've escaped the `@`, but beyond that, I don't know why it thinks the parameter `channel` is `null`.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `@`?

Comment: Please provide the headers and queries of the HTTP call